# Images are not accessible after moving Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel storage class to upload images in the storage folder. it successfully upload images and I can successfully access them by `Storage::url('path');` or   `Storage::download('path');`
however, when I copy the project to another location and try to run my copied project using `php artisan serve`, I can not access the images! this is while the original project is still fine and images are accessible.

it is noteworthy that I already used `php artisan storage:link` in the original folder. When I run `php artisan storage:link` in the copied folder it says it already exists. It is interesting that `Storage::url('path')` creates the url correctly and images are also copied correctly in the new location.

How can I fix this problem?
will this be a problem if I deploy the project in a web host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly Remove Storage Link from public folder by running

```
rm public/storage
```

And then try to run below command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked! removing the public/storage folder is the idea. because I am running on windows, I used `rmdir public\storage`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run clear cache and config. may be because of cache settings so try this

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: No mention its okay.